# cygwin ignores certain environment variables on windows 7

Tags: windows, cygwin, environment-variables, windows-7-x64

I have a windows 7 machine with Cygwin installed on it. I added a single environment variable pointing to the location of arc ( command line interface to Phabricator).

I m able to run arc on the windows commandline , but cygwin does not pick up the environment variable as expected. Output from commandline execution below.

```
Jenkins@DESKTOP-M9I6448 ~
$ which arc
which: no arc in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Users/Jenkins/tools/arcanist/bin/)

Jenkins@DESKTOP-M9I6448 ~
$ which arcanist
which: no arcanist in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Users/Jenkins/tools/arcanist/bin/)
```

Comment: Please can you provide the exact setting, and how it's added to the path in Windows (e.g. do you create and set the environment variable e.g. `ARCHANIST` and then assign the value e.g. `C:\Users\Jenkins\tools\arcanist\bin` and then append that to the PATH environment variable? Also, can you provide the relevant output of an ls command for the folder in Cygwin and the equivalent in your `cmd` window please? Then I or others can help debug the problem(s)